# Optimize function: Lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I have a function of 4 variables: (distance function)
$d(x,x_1,y,y_1 )=(x-x_1 )^2+(y-y_1 )^2$

subject to 2 constraints:
1. $g(x,x_1,y,y_1 )=ax^2+2hxy+2gx+by^2+2fy+c=0$
2. $h(x,x_1,y,y_1 )= a_1 x_1^2+2h_1 x_1 y_1+2g_1 x_1+b_1 y_1^2+2f_1 y_1+c_1=0$

Using lagrange multipliers, and partial differentiation, what should be the values of $x,x_1,y,y_1$ in terms of $a,b,c,a_1,b_1,c_1,f,g,h,f_1,g_1,h_1$, with aforementioned constraints?

Comment: Have you tried writing down the gradients of all functions involved and coming up with an equation for the Lagrange multipliers?

Comment: Yes I have tried and I have come up with equations. That was the easy part actually, the hard part is to find values of x,x1,y,y1, with which I'm struggling up to now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\nabla F= \langle \partial_x F, \partial_{x_1} F, \partial_y F, \partial_{y_1} F \rangle$. The method of Lagrange in this case requires the introduction of two multipliers. We should solve:

$$ \nabla d = \lambda_1\nabla g+ \lambda_2\nabla h $$

subject to constraints 1 and 2 as listed in your post.

The reason for this is as follows: if an extrema exists then curves $t \mapsto \alpha(t) $ which pass through the  extremal point must make $\eta=d \circ \alpha$ extreme at the corresponding point in the domain. Suppose $t=0$ gives $\alpha(0)$ the extremal point (we can shift the parameter to make this happen, nothing is lost in this convenience).

The curve $\alpha$ lies on the intersection of the level sets given by 1 and 2. We have

$$ g (\alpha(t)) =0 \qquad h( \alpha(t))=0 $$

The chain-rule yields

$$ \nabla g (\alpha(t)) \cdot \alpha'(t)=0 \qquad \nabla h (\alpha(t)) \cdot \alpha'(t)=0 $$

Likewise, since $\eta$ is extremal at $t=0$ the chain rule gives

$$ \nabla d (\alpha(0)) \cdot \alpha'(0)=0 $$

Summarizing, the tangent vector field $\alpha'$ is orthogonal to the gradient fields of $g$ and $h$ where they can be compared **and** at $\alpha(0)$ the tangent $\alpha'(0)$ is orthogonal to $\nabla d$. The point $\alpha(0)$ is special in that we obtain orthogonality with respect to $\nabla d, \nabla g$ and $\nabla h$.

At first glance this would not appear to connect $\nabla d, \nabla g$ and $\nabla h$ in any particular way. However, there is not just one curve on the constraint surface. Provided the constraints 1. and 2. are nondegenerate the level set they define is two-dimensional and there will be a two-dimensional plane of tangent vectors which are found orthogonal to $\nabla d, \nabla g$ and $\nabla h$. But, this means that $\nabla d, \nabla g$ and $\nabla h$ are linearly dependent since $\mathbb{R}^4$ should be the direct sum of the tangent and normal space. For these reasons we introduce multipliers to ascertain the location of the max/min solution.

Notice the method is based on the existence of extreme solutions. For the continuous function $d$ these are known to exist if the constraint is a compact surface. Sometimes the method still "works" for non-compact constraints, but beware the limit of the method.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't really understand what you wrote, this math is too advanced for me. Would it be possible to explain this at a high-school level? If not, I will be absolutely ok with it. I just need to know whether a high school student is able to solve this. Thanks.